# include navigation.php creating file path error

Tags: php, navigation, include, filepath

I have decided to swap my standard html navigation for a php include, i have a multi deirectory site so have had to include the file using ../ to move up the directories where applicable.

When using the navigation from my root folder it works fine but when i then try and use the same navigation in a subdirectory file my file paths get added onto the end of the current path for example.

http://example.co.uk/catagoryOne/catagoryTwo/index.php

Becomes:

http://example.co.uk/catagoryOne/catagoryTwo/catagoryOne/catagoryThree/index.php

Where i need it to be:

http://example.co.uk/catagoryOne/catagoryThree/index.php

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Many thanks in advance

P.S. Apologies if this is not clear please let me know if anything requires further clarification.

Comment: I get voted down for what? Asking a question? This site should be a place that encourages people to learn from each other not push people away by voting down question by those who obviously lack expierence in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be solved via `.htaccess` as it is to do with url?

[Read more on `.htaccess` here](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem i used

```
 <li><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/catagoryOne/catagoryThree/index.php"></li>
```

within navigation.php where applicable.